# Anyone having issues with WikipediaKit? July 2023

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, network-programming, wikipedia-api

I've been using Wikipediakit in my swift/ios app for some time now, it's always worked fine. Suddenly it's stopped (just as I shipped it to the app store, annoyingly), and I'm getting a 'badResponse' error from the API. On the github repo there is a week old discussion saying the creator has discontinued his app that's build with Wikipediakit due to an API no longer functioning, and the library hasn't been updated in years, so sounds potentially like it's defunct. Can anyone confirm this? Anyone currently using it successfully? TIA!

```
        let _ = wikipedia.requestArticle(language: language, title: albumTitle, imageWidth: 5) { result in
        
        switch result {
            
        case .success(let article):
         
            var image: UIImage?
            
            do {
                if let safeImage = article.imageURL {
                    
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: safeImage)
                    
                   
                        image = UIImage(data: data)
                    
                   
                }
               
                
            } catch {
                print("error loading image")
            }
            
            self.delegate?.didUpdateAlbumInfo(albumInfo: article.displayText, imageURL: image)
           
        case .failure(let error):
            print("there has been an error grabbing from wiki: \(error)")
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Developer got back to me - API is indeed broken: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T328036